# extract specific text from string using javascript

Tags: javascript

I have specific string stored in variable. However I need only `<4854D382GA9@example.com>`.

example string:

> X-PHP-Originating-Script: 0:acr.php
>
> x: <193@example.com>
>
> MIME-Version: 1.0
>
> Content-Type: text/plain; charset=US-ASCII;
>
> Format=flowed
>
> Text-ID: <4854D382GA9@example.com>
>
> Date: Sun, 02 Jul 2017 12:22:12 +0500

how can I achieve this using javascript ?

Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: You should parse the string and look for a suitable pattern. What have you tried? What are the rules for matching that particular string, e.g. "the bit after Text-ID:" or "the second email address" or …?

Comment: Maybe google "javascript email regex".

Comment: 1.  Split the string by line.  2.  Find the line that starts with `"Text-ID:"`  3. Get the last part of that line.  Remove the `<>`.  Show us your code and we'll help you with it.

Comment: I am knew to javascript. I can use RegEx in php to get that text. But I want to know how can I get in javascript.

Comment: You can use a regexp pattern like: Text-ID: (\S*) - see https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions for details

Comment: Why is this a dupe of your other [question for PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45137105/extract-specific-text-from-string-using-php)?

Comment: @RobG I need to alert <4854D382GA9@example.com> which is after Text-ID. Doesn't need to remove <>

Comment: Do not put information in comments, put them in your post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
var str = `X-PHP-Originating-Script: 0:acr.php

x: <193@example.com>

MIME-Version: 1.0

Content-Type: text/plain; charset=US-ASCII;

Format=flowed

Text-ID: <4854D382GA9@example.com>

Date: Sun, 02 Jul 2017 12:22:12 +0500`;

var matches = str.match(/Text-ID:\s(.+)/);
console.log(matches[1]);
```

Comment: Code-only answers are pointless, especially when the OP doesn't describe the issue correctly. Also, the OP has made zero attempt at writing code, so you're just providing a free service to one individual as this answer will be of no use to others. :-(

Comment: @RobG good point. Didn't feel like there was much to add here but will keep that in mind!